# How to connect to HTTP Rest API that authenticates with LDAP

Tags: ruby, http, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I am writing a Ruby script to connect to a REST API website.
The website is authenticated by using LDAP / SSO using the AD credentials, so no basic authentication or user/password has to be provided.

This is the code so far:

```
resource_http = Net::HTTP.new(webserver.company.com, 443)
resource_http.use_ssl = true
resource_http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
resource_request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/api/endpoint")
resource_request.set_form_data({"chocolate"=>"yes","beer"=>"yes"})
resource_response = resource_http.request(resource_request)
```

But I receive an authorization error:

```
Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Authorization Required
```

Playing with Net::LDAP, I'm able to authenticate my credentials on my computer:

```
ldap = Net::LDAP.new
ldap.host = "ldap.company.com"
ldap.port = "389"
ldap.auth "user@company.com", "password"
ldap.bind
```

But I have no idea how to "attach" or pass this LDAP info in the HTTP request.

All my Google searches point me to enabling SSO/authentication on a website app, but I'm not trying to do that, I want to connect with my Ruby script to an existing LDAP authenticated website.

**Update #1**
Some Ruby forums pointed me to the gem HTTPI and using a 'curb' adapter. This adapter relies on the Curl library to handle the Kerberos/SPNEGO authentication.
However I was unable to make the curb installer work with the curl library they link on their website (for a Windows computer).

I moved the code to Python using the kerberos module. I'm able to generate the ticket and append it on the HTTP request headers, which get authenticated by the REST API and return the data I want.

I'm still learning, so even if my code works on Python I'd like to be able to make it work on Ruby.

Sample code in Python:
https://gist.github.com/DevOpsCow/d374300304d7beef8a03

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here's a little advice: Don't say it's a dumb question and then urge us to be gentle. Ask good questions, make sure you've done your research and provide the necessary information. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 and http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html are good reading.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could pass credentials over HTTP. I would be surprised if the REST API allowed you to pass in host/port information of your LDAP server (this could be a huge security hole). The most likely scenario is that you need to provide a username and a password in a form that the REST API expects it. The REST API will then perform the authentication to the LDAP server and depending on the authentication results, you will get the corresponding response / status from the REST API back.

Long story short, you need to get information from the administrator of the REST API (or from the API documentation) to see how you are expected authenticate over HTTP.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a `401 Authorization required` the server has to also provide an `www-authenticate`-Header that contains more information on how to authenticate. Have a look for that and check the information given.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, I was trying to use postman to send authenticate against an API that uses LDAP. 
One of the gun devs I work with helped me out,  it ended up that I had to use DOMAIN\username in the username field. It worked after that.

Comment: Maybe show some code snippet here? -- that will help others to understand this more clearly.